# How to build images in beaglebone black?

Tags: beagleboneblack

When pressing S2 and powering the BeagleBoard using USB -> 1 ampere power adapter (without anything else connected), just the power LED is on, the other LEDs remain off. I've tried pressing the S2 button for a minute, and just a few seconds. No change.

I then purchased a 5V -> USB cable. I've read that the USB power connector is hardware restricted to 0.5 ampere. I did not have a 2 ampere power adapter, but I later read that the USB power of 0.5 ampere should be sufficient.

I've tried to boot the SD with both the 5V power cable (1 ampere) and mini USB power (0.5 amp) by pressing the power button for 10 seconds, which will turn the device off, and then powering it on again while pressing the S2 button. Just the power LED lids up, no other LEDs.

What could be the cause that the BeagleBoard isn't booting? Is the regular boot (factory default) to a cursor an indication that the board may be broken?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's hardware related

Comment: JFTR, sounds like the board is dead. It shouldn't draw >1A without doing anything.